# Creating a symlink for docker-volumes to another directory

Tags: docker, symbolic-link

For reasons I need to symlink `/var/lib/docker/volumes` into `/net/datadisc/disc1/docker_volumes`, i.e. ever volume that docker creates inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes` would instead be created in `/net/datadisc/disc1/docker_volumes`

`sudo ln -s /net/datadisc/disc1/docker_volumes /var/lib/docker/volumes` doesn't do it.

Comment: The permissions in `/var/lib/docker` are very restrictive, so you need to do this as root (or with sudo). Also, I assume the permissions of the target directory should match those of `/var/lib/docker/volumes` (`drwx-----x` on my system).

Comment: You could use the "--volume" option while creating the docker container and specify the required directory path which you want to use for data storage.
i.e. : docker run -it -v <host/path>:<container/path> -d image_name